# Token class implementation

Tags: c++, c++11

I have implemented `Token` and `FieldToken` classes as part of my [project](https://github.com/m-peko/booleval) and would like to hear some suggestions for improvement.

First, `Token` class represents logical operators, relational operators, parentheses, etc. It does not hold a value, only type of the token (e.g. `AND`, `OR`, etc.). Here is its implementation:

## Token.h

```
class Token {
public:
    enum class Type : uint8_t {
        UNKNOWN = 0,
        FIELD   = 1,

        // Logical operators
        AND = 2,
        OR  = 3,

        // Relational operators
        NEQ = 4,
        GT  = 5,
        LT  = 6,

        // Parentheses
        LP = 7,
        RP = 8
    };

public:
    Token() noexcept;
    Token(Token&& other) = default;
    Token(Token const& other) = default;
    Token(Type const type) noexcept;

    Token& operator=(Token&& other) = default;
    Token& operator=(Token const& other) = default;
    bool operator==(Token const& other) const noexcept;

    virtual ~Token() = default;

    virtual void type(Type const type) noexcept;
    Type type() const noexcept;

    bool is(Type const type) const noexcept;
    bool is_not(Type const type) const noexcept;
    bool is_one_of(Type const type1, Type const type2) const noexcept;

    template <typename... Types>
    bool is_one_of(Type const type1, Type const type2, Types const ... types) const noexcept;

    static std::unordered_map<std::string, Type> type_expressions() noexcept;

private:
    Type type_;
};

template <typename... Types>
bool Token::is_one_of(Type const type1, Type const type2, Types const ... types) const noexcept {
    return is(type1) || is_one_of(type2, types...);
}
```

## Token.cpp

```
Token::Token() noexcept
    : type_(Type::UNKNOWN)
{}

Token::Token(Type const type) noexcept
    : type_(type)
{}

bool Token::operator==(Token const& other) const noexcept {
    return type_ == other.type_;
}

void Token::type(Type const type) noexcept {
    type_ = type;
}

Token::Type Token::type() const noexcept {
    return type_;
}

bool Token::is(Type const type) const noexcept {
    return type_ == type;
}

bool Token::is_not(Type const type) const noexcept {
    return type_ != type;
}

bool Token::is_one_of(Type const type1, Type const type2) const noexcept {
    return is(type1) || is(type2);
}

std::unordered_map<std::string, Token::Type> Token::type_expressions() noexcept {
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, Type> type_expressions = {
        { "and",     Type::AND },
        { "&&" ,     Type::AND },
        { "or" ,     Type::OR },
        { "||" ,     Type::OR },
        { "neq",     Type::NEQ },
        { "!="  ,    Type::NEQ },
        { "greater", Type::GT },
        { ">",       Type::GT },
        { "less",    Type::LT },
        { "<",       Type::LT },
        { "(",       Type::LP },
        { ")",       Type::RP }
    };
    return type_expressions;
}
```

Now, `FieldToken` class represents all other tokens, usually strings whose value I need to know. Therefore, I derived `Token` class to preserve all the functionality and added field value as a new data member.

## FieldToken.h

```
template <typename FieldType = std::string>
class FieldToken : public Token {
public:
    FieldToken() noexcept;
    FieldToken(FieldToken&& other) = default;
    FieldToken(FieldToken const& other) = default;
    FieldToken(FieldType const& field) noexcept;

    FieldToken& operator=(FieldToken&& other) = default;
    FieldToken& operator=(FieldToken const& other) = default;
    bool operator==(FieldToken const& other) const noexcept;

    virtual ~FieldToken() = default;

    void type(Type const type) noexcept override;

    void field(FieldType const& field) noexcept;
    FieldType const& field() const noexcept;

private:
    template <typename T>
    void ignore(T&&);

private:
    FieldType field_;
};

template <typename FieldType>
FieldToken<FieldType>::FieldToken() noexcept
    : Token(Token::Type::FIELD),
      field_{}
{}

template <typename FieldType>
FieldToken<FieldType>::FieldToken(FieldType const& field) noexcept
    : Token(Token::Type::FIELD),
      field_(field)
{}

template <typename FieldType>
void FieldToken<FieldType>::type(Type const type) noexcept {
    ignore(type);
    Token::type(Token::Type::FIELD);
}

template <typename FieldType>
void FieldToken<FieldType>::field(FieldType const& field) noexcept {
    field_ = field;
}

template <typename FieldType>
FieldType const& FieldToken<FieldType>::field() const noexcept {
    return field_;
}

template <typename FieldType>
template <typename T>
void FieldToken<FieldType>::ignore(T&&)
{}
```

What do you think? Any implementation or logical suggestions are welcomed...

Answer (score 2):

## Make `type_expressions` a const member variable

Why have a function returning a `std::unordered_map<>` with constant data, if you can just as well declare this map directly as a member variable? Declare this in the header file:

```
class Token {
    ...
public:
    static const std::unordered_map<std::string, Type> type_expressions;
    ...
};
```

And the following in the implementation file:

```
const std::unordered_map<std::string, Type> Token::type_expressions = {
    {"and", Type::AND},
    ...
};
```

## Consider having `Token` just be a `class enum`

Your class `Token` is not very generic. It works like an `enum`, with just two differences: it has a `is_one_of()` convenience function, and there's a map from strings to `Type`. But it has a hardcoded set of `Types`. I recommend just doing:

```
enum class Token: uint8_t {
    UNKNOWN,
    FIELD,
    ...
};
```

Have the map from strings to types just be a non-class variable, and defining `is_one_of()` as a generic function that can compare any set of things:

````
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
bool is_one_of(T const value, T const value1, Ts const ... values) {
    return value == value1 || is_one_of(value, values...);
}

template<typename T>
bool is_one_of(T const value, T const value1) {
    return value == value1;
}
```
````

Comment: Is your is_one_of template right? https://ideone.com/PZ5kT1

Comment: @nomanpouigt No it's not, I always forget you can't have a variable number of arguments with the same type this way.